# Recursive Iteration looping forever after first

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I have very simple code, that for a SOSA STRADONITZ number returns the generation of the person:

1 is 1

2-3 is 2

4-7 is 3

8-15 is 4

16-13 is 5

(...)

The code is the follwing, but it does not return ever after the second point, why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        FamilyTree f = new FamilyTree(null);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            f.getGeneration(i);
            System.out.println("returned!");
        }
    }

public int getGeneration(int sosa) {
        System.out.println("SOSA: " + sosa);
        int toRet = 1;
        while ((int) sosa / 2 != 0) {
            toRet++;
            getGeneration((int) sosa / 2);
        }
        return toRet;
    }
```

it prints:

SOSA: 1

returned!

SOSA: 2

SOSA: 1

SOSA: 1

SOSA: 1

(SOSA: 1) forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `while` loop is entered, there is no way to terminate, as you never change `sosa`. Dividing it by 2 each time in the loop will fix this.

A few other notes:

- You can initialize `toRet` to `0` and check for `sosa` being non-zero rather than `sosa / 2` being non-zero.
- There is no need to cast `sosa / 2` to `int` as the result of the division of two `int`s is guaranteed to be an `int`.

```java
public int getGeneration(int sosa) {
    int toRet = 0;
    while (sosa != 0) {
        toRet++;
        sosa /= 2;
    }
    return toRet;
}
```

This can also be simplified by looking at the binary representation of the input:

```java
return 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(sosa);
```

Comment: So just doing "sosa =" on the getGeneration inside the while does solve it as well.

Comment: @FabioAbreu No, that doesn't give the right output. That returns `3` for input of `8`.

Comment: Since you're essentially calculating the base 2 log, you need to divide `sosa` by `2` each time.

Comment: @Umitigated alright gotcha, that makes sense.